# How does one spoil their moderator election vote?

Tags: discussion, voting, moderator-election

It's common in elections around the world for one to have the ability to spoil their vote. This is the action of deliberately filing a vote which cannot be counted. It is not a fraudulent vote, as those who legally spoil their vote only vote once, but it cannot be counted. The purpose is to express some sort of disapproval, in displaying that one is willing to vote, but is not willing to dedicate their vote to any option.

How does one spoil their vote in a moderator election on Stack Overflow?

Comment: What is the problem with just... not voting?

Comment: Do you mean [**spoil** their vote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoilt_vote), as in a [protest vote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protest_vote)?

Comment: What exactly would you be communicating disapproval of by doing this?

Comment: I think the clearest message one might want to communicate by doing so would be "none of these candidates are suitable for the position."  While Stack Overflow has so far had the good fortune to have had good candidates in all of its elections, I could imagine, in some hypothetical election, wanting to express that none of the candidates are suitable for the position, even if that has no effect on the outcome of the election.

Comment: I believe that the answer to your question is "you can't", but someone with more experience with the ballot format/detailed election mechanics could perhaps confirm that.

Comment: From *[Protest vote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protest_vote)* (my emphasis): *"A protest vote (also called a blank, null,* ***spoiled,*** *or "none of the above" vote) is a vote cast in an election to demonstrate dissatisfaction with the choice of candidates or the current political system. Protest voting takes a variety of forms and reflects numerous voter motivations, including political apathy. Where voting is compulsory, casting a blank vote is available for those who do not wish to choose a candidate, or to protest. Unlike abstention elsewhere, blank votes are counted."*

Comment: By visiting the election page, selecting someone, earning your badge, then unselecting them and moving on.

Comment: Unless you find a bug, it can't be done. Perhaps you can change this into a feature request for something like a "None of the above" voting choice.

Comment: "It's common in elections around the world for one to have the ability to soil their vote." That’s not exactly a deliberate feature in most (all) systems. It’s just a reality of many analogue voting systems that one can input garbage.

Comment: We're not exactly voting for presidents here. Comparing the moderator election to "elections around the world" is just not realistic. We're just committing to a more digital version of writing names on the back of a beer coaster. I'd even argue that you may want to vote for people you *don't* like. You'll be enabling them to spend a lot of their free time doing pretty grindy work.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Actually, there are several countries and jurisdictions that allow such a vote https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/None_of_the_above, with the explicit intent of allowing people to participate in an election and say "None of the candidates are suitable".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You cannot spoil your moderator election vote, nor is there any option in the [Single Transferable Vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77541/how-are-moderator-election-votes-counted-in-plain-english) algorithm as applied by [OpaVote](https://www.opavote.com/methods/single-transferable-vote) to have a '*none of the candidates meet my expectation*' vote.

Your only option is to not vote. Or, if you like the hassle,  do what [Kevin B](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/429352/how-does-one-spoil-their-moderator-election-vote#comment989875_429352) suggested:

> By visiting the election page, selecting someone, earning your badge, then unselecting them and moving on

But we don't keep stats for that and I'm not bothered to do that analysis for past elections.

If you have concerns about candidates, the election, current moderators, or process and policies on the site, you are more likely to be heard when you post on Meta ([but don't die trying](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-and-not-die-trying)) so we can have a reasonable exchange of ideas to extend our common understanding of how we as a community (should) operate.